# Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: null

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, database-connection

Getting below response from my database server in local machine,

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-22T13:18:30.383+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: \"Host '192.168.64.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server\"",
    "path": "/users"
}
```

My Spring boot `application.properties`

```
# MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.64.2:3306/ctracker
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin

logging.level.org.springframework=info
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
```

Phpmyadmin console:

[image]

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Spring boot stack trace,

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '192.168.64.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
```

Comment: try a show grant 'admin'@'192.168.64.1' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html the user doesn't seem to have the right to access your database

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the issue by adding new user in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by [adding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/how-to-create-separate-users-in-phpmyadmin-each-one-cant-see-others-databases) new user in phpmyadmin,

> 1. Login to phpMyADmin.
> 2. Go to Privileges.
> 3. Click Add a new User.
> 4. Type the access info you want in the Login Information area (username, host, password)
> 5. Click on the radio button for Create database with same name and grant all privileges.
> 6. Click Go.